# C++-How I acces to this variable from outside?

Tags: c++

`double OLDVal[] = { *(double*)ccy1 };` I have this, I wanted to declare OLDVal globally...so I can access to it from everywhere

`double OLDVal[];` // global declariation, now I want to give it a value from a function...

```
  OLDVal[] = { *(double*)ccy1 }; //but this doesn't work
```

I hope you guys understand me !

Comment: why do you need an array of 1 element?

Comment: _"I hope you guys understand me !"_ No. It's completely unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: I *guess* you want to declare the variable using `extern double OLDVal[];` and later define it using `double OldVal[] = { ... };`

Comment: OLDval[0] = \*(double\*)ccy1;

Comment: You should read some articles about [why global variables are evil](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+global+variables+are+evil&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  Also search the internet for "c++ encapsulation".

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector` and not array.  Prefer to pass the `vector` by reference instead of using a global variable.

Comment: What is `ccy1`?

Comment: @JustinTime 
 
textuploader.com/ddg0b  maybe you undestand

Comment: So, `OLDVal` is a `double[1]`, and the line that's giving you problems is `OLDVal[1] = { *(double*)ccy1 };`?  If so, that's because arrays are zero-indexed in C++: For any array `T[N]`, of type `T` and size `N`, all unsigned integers in the range of `0..(N - 1)`, inclusive, are valid indexes (e.g. for an array `double arr[5]`, the following are valid: `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]`, `arr[3]`, and `arr[4]`; `arr[5]` would be the next memory address past the end of the array, and not actually an element of the array itself).  In your case, since your array is `double[1]`, you want `OLDVal[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing to what you are trying to do is to declare the array in a header with the `extern` keyword and define it in a source file or, if you are working with only one source file, add something like

```
double OLDVal[1]; // replace 1 with whatever your array size is.
```

before you define / use the array in any function.

If this doesn't work, please provide a little more (unambiguous) information on what you are trying to do. Good luck.

Comment: OK I will try, if I won't work may I send you a bigger Code ? just a little bigger?

Comment: @AkinUnknown _" just a little bigger?"_ Can you at least provide a [MCVE] with a little bit more context?

Comment: @AkinUnknown Fix your question dude!

Comment: In Java it goes like that:

Comment: I declare a variable e.g "static int e=0;" ...if I change it from anywhere to "e=2;" it replaces the static value to 2...and it doesn't matter where I use "e" it takes the last changed value and not 0...in this case "2"